# Why does the memory address of a struct reference change?

Tags: pointers, go, struct, reference, pass-by-reference

I have a struct and a method that's working on the structs reference. The pointer address is changing every time I call the method. Why is it like that?

Code

```
package main

import "k8s.io/contrib/compare/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/emicklei/go-restful/log"

type Whatever struct{
    Name string
}

func (whatever *Whatever) GetNameByReference() (string) {
log.Printf("Whatever.GetNameByReference() memory address: %v", &whatever)

    return whatever.Name
}

func evaluateMemoryAddressWhenNotWritingAnything()  {
    whatever := Whatever{}

    whatever.GetNameByReference()
    whatever.GetNameByReference()
    whatever.GetNameByReference()
}

func main() {
    evaluateMemoryAddressWhenNotWritingAnything()
}
```

Output:

```
log.go:30: Whatever.GetNameByReference() memory address: 0xc420034020
log.go:30: Whatever.GetNameByReference() memory address: 0xc420034030
log.go:30: Whatever.GetNameByReference() memory address: 0xc420034038
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Never think and never talk about references. Go has no notion of "reference", everything is a value. Some things are pointer values. Your problem stems from thinking about `*X` as "a reference to an X" which it isn't: It is a value holding the memory address of an `X` (or nil).

So in `func (whatever *Whatever)` the variable `whatever` is a pointer to a `Whatever`. The value of `whatever` is the memory address of the `Whatever` the pointer points to. You would like to print this memory address, i.e. the value of `whatever`.

You do `Printf("%v", &whatever)`. Remember: `whatever` is a variable (holding a memory address). So `&whatever` is the address of the variable itself: `&whatever` is of type `**Whatever`. What you find at the address `&whatever` is *not* the value you are interested in; it is just the temporary variable used to store the address of the original `Whatever`. Of course this temporary variable is not pinned in memory an may change freely.

You should do `Printf("%p", whatever)`. The verb `%p` is for pointer values and `whatever`is a pointer and you are interested in its value, so print this value.

Comment: Btw: You should come up with better names. Distinguishing `whatever` and `Whatever` is basically impossible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, great answer! Regarding the naming, I don't like using abbrevations and I not sure about using self / this.. any other idea?

Comment: In Go it would be `func (w *Whatever)`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not displaying the address of the struct, you are displaying the address of the address (address of the pointer). The pointer is passed as a parameter and thus new each time. Remove the & in `log.Printf("Whatever.GetNameByReference() memory address: %v", &whatever)` to get what you want (and use %p instead of %v).

Answer (score 0):

Calling method

```
func (whatever *Whatever) GetNameByReference() (string) {
```

is much the same as calling function providing receiver as first argument

```
func GetNameByReference(whatever *Whatever) (string) {
```

Go calling convention is to always pass arguments copy_by_value. So each time you call  `whatever.GetNameByReference()` it receives fresh copy of `whatever` which itself holds same `*Whatever` address. As already written doing

```
log.Printf("Whatever.GetNameByReference() memory address: %v", whatever) //instead of &whatever
```

will log the same `whatever` value which is address.

Comment: Thanks, the learning.. not quite what is was looking for, but great learning. Thx